# Line chart android

Tags: android

I am  working on android project and in my project I need line graph,the graph should be like image displayed below .

[image: Line chart]

Please help me :),
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a achartengine

http://www.achartengine.org/

A tutorial of line graph

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ThKImy6PPM

http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Drawing-graphs-in-Android-using-aChartEngine-charting-library-(Line-Charts)

Answer (score 1):

Use any 3rd party library.....

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/8260-android-charts-framework.html

http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Answer (score 0):

use AndroidPlot for Graph its very easy to use:

http://androidplot.com/